# Proof of state updating

Tags: agda

My code is

```hs
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true; false)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_)
open import Data.String using (String; _==_)

var : Set
var = String

data value : Set where
  valₙ  : ℕ → value
  valₒ  : Bool → value
  undef : value

state = var → value

-- states updating
_[_↦_] : state → var → value → state
(s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x with x₁ == x
... | false = s x
... | true = v

s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 {s} {s'} {x₁} {x₂} {v} c x₁=x₂ = {!  !}

s[x↦v]-eq2 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ false → s' x₂ ≡ s x₂
s[x↦v]-eq2 {s} {s'} {x₁} {x₂} {v} c x₁!=x₂ = {!  !}
```

Is there a method to prove above two propositions? Why `refl` is not working?

Comment: problem is solved, just use rewrite...

Comment: you may want to write an answer?

Comment: I know you already found your answer but could you add a brief explanation of what you are trying to do for future readers?

Comment: Welcome to PASE! Questions and answers with only code snippets and little explanation isn't very well received on StackExchange sites, because they are not just written for your own benefit, but for all future readers. Would you mind including more details?

Comment: @Trebor ok, it is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asker's existing answer is syntactically invalid, so I thought I would correct it and provide some reasoning. I will consider just `s[x↦v]-eq1`; the reasoning for the other property is identical. The desired property is as follows:

```hs
s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 c x₁=x₂ = ?
```

Looking at this, I notice that the variable `s′` is universally quantified, then soon after equated to an independent term. We can immediately simplify this situation, removing `s′`, by matching the variable `c : s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ])` to `refl : (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ])`. This leaves the following problem:

```hs
s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl x₁=x₂ = ?
  -- ? : {s : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x₂ ≡ v
```

Now we can consider `(s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x₂`. To make this term compute, we have to do the same pattern matching as in the definition of `_[_↦_]`. In our case, this means starting with a `with x₁ == x₂`. This has two effects: as we intended, `x₁ == x₂` is abstracted from the definition of `_[_↦_]` (which is hard to notate, but I use the `| z` notation Agda prints), and also `x₁ == x₂` is abstracted from the type of `x₁=x₂`, making that type `z ≡ true`.

```hs
s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl x₁=x₂ with x₁ == x₂
... | z = ?
  -- ? : {s : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → z ≡ true → ((s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x₂ | z) ≡ v
```

`z ≡ true` is a very promising equation because one side (the left) is a variable. Therefore, we can match on it. Notice that this removes the `z` we just introduced, and also our application of `_[_↦_]` computes.

```hs
s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl x₁=x₂ with x₁ == x₂
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl refl | .true = ?
  -- ? : {s : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → ((s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x₂ | true) ≡ v
  -- ? : {s : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} →                          v ≡ v
```

After computing, the answer is clear. Optionally, we can notice that a with-abstraction on the LHS followed by a match on the proof of the equation is exactly what `rewrite` does (well, `rewrite` also does a with-abstraction over the proof of the equation, but that doesn't make a difference in this case), and use that to condense the definition a little, as follows:

```hs
s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl x₁=x₂ rewrite x₁=x₂ = refl
```

In conclusion, here is the full working solution:

````hs
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true; false)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; refl)
open import Data.String using (String; _==_)

var : Set
var = String

data value : Set where
  valₙ  : ℕ → value
  valₒ  : Bool → value
  undef : value

state = var → value

-- states updating
_[_↦_] : state → var → value → state
(s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x with x₁ == x
... | false = s x
... | true = v

s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 refl x₁=x₂ rewrite x₁=x₂ = refl

s[x↦v]-eq2 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ false → s' x₂ ≡ s x₂
s[x↦v]-eq2 refl x₁!=x₂ rewrite x₁!=x₂ = refl
```
````

Comment: Thanks for correct me ! I noticed that I forget add the `|` between two definitional equalities in the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

```hs
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc)
open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true; false)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_)
open import Data.String using (String; _==_)

var : Set
var = String

data value : Set where
  valₙ  : ℕ → value
  valₒ  : Bool → value
  undef : value

state = var → value

-- states updating
_[_↦_] : state → var → value → state
(s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) x with x₁ == x
... | false = s x
... | true = v

s[x↦v]-eq1 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ true → s' x₂ ≡ v
s[x↦v]-eq1 {s} {s'} {x₁} {x₂} {v} c x₁=x₂ rewrite c | x₁=x₂ = refl

s[x↦v]-eq2 : {s s' : state} {x₁ x₂ : var} {v : value} → s' ≡ (s [ x₁ ↦ v ]) → (x₁ == x₂) ≡ false → s' x₂ ≡ s x₂
s[x↦v]-eq2 {s} {s'} {x₁} {x₂} {v} c x₁!=x₂ rewrite c | x₁!=x₂ = refl
```

I thought that the given explicit definitioanl equalities are sufficient to prove the result by `refl`. But it still requires to apply these equality by `rewrite`. To be honest, I think it is a litte redundant.

EDIT: fix a typo.

Comment: It would be nice if you could briefly explain what the code does and how did you come up with it.